# Loading Liferay Properties from Spring IoC container (to get jdbc connection parameters)

Tags: spring, properties, liferay

I'm developing some portlets for Liferay Portal 5.2.3 with bundled tomcat 6.0.18 using Spring IoC container. 
I need to map the `User_` table used in Liferay database to an entity with Hibernate, so I need to use two different dataSources to separate the liferay db from the db used by portlets.

My `jdbc.properties` has to hold all connection parameters for both databases: no problem for the one used by portlets, but I am having issues determining which database uses liferay to hold its data.

My conclusion is that i should have something like this:

```
liferayConnection.url=jdbc:hsqldb:${liferay.home}/data/hsql/lportal
```

in order to get the database url dynamically loaded, according to Liferay properties found in portal-ext.properties. (Or, better, load the whole `portal-ext.properties` and read database properties from there).

The problem is that the placeholder is not resolved:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'liferayDataSource' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'liferay.home'
```

To dodge this problem I tried to load explicitly `portal-ext.properties` with a Spring bean:

```
<bean id="liferayPropertiesConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="../../portal-ext.properties"/>
```

but no luck: liferay.home is not resolved but there aren't other errors.

How can I resolve the placeholder defined by Liferay? Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify... you have two sets of properties, one in `jdbc.properties`, and another in `portal-ext.properties`?

Comment: exactly, skaffman. 
now i realized that my bean liferayPropertiesConfigurer can't load portal-ext.properties, so i guess it's a matter of classpath. 
can i access files that are outside my application? Can I use relative paths like ../../etc.properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PropsUtil` class (from Liferay)  to get values of `portal-ext.properties`.

```java
String value = PropsUtil.get("key");
```

Comment: thanks Rutvij, I think I'll try to do that. Should be easy in Spring container. In the meanwhile, I hardcoded the jdbc parameters in another .properties file.

Answer (score 0):

For loading properties files from an *applicationContext.xml* file I usually use the *PropertiesFactoryBean* specifying the *location* property with a the name of the file located in the classpath, like this:

```
<bean name="myHibernateProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Make sure the properties files are in a folder/package that is in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `PropsUtil` using SpringEL. for example:

```
#{T(com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PropsUtil).get('liferay.home')}
```

I haven't tried exactly this. but you could load the liferay properties that you need with the following:

```
<util:properties id="liferayProps">
    <prop key="liferay.home">#{T(com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PropsUtil).get('liferay.home')}</prop>
</util:properties>
```